# If I have a string of HTML code, how can I use JQuery to parse it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var html = '<div class="item">abcabc<span>sasd</span></div>';
```

How can I use JQuery to retrieve the stuff inside "item"?
I want to get the HTML inside of this item...as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the root of your HTML string is that `.item`, it's simply a matter of passing the whole string into the `$()` function and invoking `.html()` on the jQuery-wrapped element:

```
var string = $(html).html(); // 'abcabc<span>sasd</span>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
var html = $('<div class="item">abcabc<span>sasd</span></div>');
var content = $(".item", html).html();
```

Comment: `.item` is the root element in the string, so `$(".item", html)` actually finds `.item .item`, which is incorrect.